# How to build a vue.js project with index, css and js in one folder

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have created a vue.js project using "vue init webpack my-project". When I do "npm run build" it creates js and css directory in dist folder. I want that all the files to be present in root folder. Is that possible?

Here's my config/index.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {

  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: '',
    assetsPublicPath: '',

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: true,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
}
```

Comment: You want the output to be in the root folder?? How about accidentally overriding files??

Comment: Is that a possibility? Because all the files in js folder have \*.js\* suffix and similarly all the files in css folder have \*.css\* suffix.

Comment: Naturally, it depends on the project and what files are present at what folders. What I mean is outputting in the root may lead to overwritting. Maybe not now, while you are vigilant, but in the future this may lead to some pretty WTF moments.

Comment: And what have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: @acdcjunior...It is a small project and having all the files in one directory is a hard requirement set by server. (I know, it is a weird requirement)

Comment: @EmileBergeron...I have a workaround ready in which I use a python script to change the paths in index.html and copy css and js files in the root directory. I do this after "npm run build" exits i.e after dist folder is created. I could not find a way of doing this through webpack.

Comment: if you do want to implement it, open `webpack.config.js`, then modify `output.path`

Comment: @Sphinx....it worked. Had to change "utils.assetsPath"